# watermark:imaggttftext is not working

Tags: php

I am trying to watermark the image but the watermark text is not appearing in my image.

```
<?php
/*
image.php
*/

header("Content-type: image/png");
$imgPath = 'image.png';

$image = imagecreatefrompng($imgPath);
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 110, 110, 110);

$string = "stack overflow";

$fontSize = 6;

$imageHeight = imagesy($image);
$distanceY = 50;
$maxImageStrings = max(8, $imageHeight / $distanceY);

$x = 15;    

$font='sansfont.ttf';
for ($i = 0; $i < $maxImageStrings; $i++) {
$y = $i * $distanceY;
//imagestring($image, $fontSize, $x, $y, $string, $color);
imagettftext($image, 200, 0, 10, 20, $color, $font, $string);
}

imagepng($image);
```

Thanks is advance

Comment: What exactly is not working? Add that info to your post

Comment: Check the name of the font and ensure you have the correct path to it

Comment: I just checked 1) name of the font is correct 2) font is in the same directory as the script file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as far as I found when testing, was the font name and - most likely also, the path to the font.

You could use a method like this:

```
putenv('GDFONTPATH='.realpath( $fontpath ) );
$fontpath=getenv('GDFONTPATH');
$font = $fontpath . $fontname;
```

However, ignoring the paths I use here the following produces many text entries on the picture

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    $imgPath = realpath( 'C:\data\Archives\Images\34378.png' );

    $image = imagecreatefrompng($imgPath);
    $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 110, 110, 110);

    $string = "stack overflow";

    $fontSize =6;

    $imageHeight = imagesy($image);
    $distanceY = 50;
    $maxImageStrings = max(8, $imageHeight / $distanceY);

    $x = 15;    

    $font='c:\wwwroot\inc\fonts\arial.ttf';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $maxImageStrings; $i++) {
        $y = $i * $distanceY;
        imagestring($image, $fontSize, $x, $y, $string, $color);
    }
    imagepng($image);
?>
```

The important thing was the correct fontpath!!

Comment: thanks bro it works i just added this line putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   $image=imagecreatefrompng("image.png");
    $watermarktext="image.png";
    $font="sansfont.ttf";
    $fontsize="15";
    $white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
    imagettftext($image, $fontsize, 0, 20, 10, $white, $font, $watermarktext);
    header("Content-type:image/png");
    imagepng($image);
    imagedestroy($image);
```

or other solution put your text as a png image then try

```
    header('content-type: image/jpeg'); 



    // creating png image of watermark
    $watermark = imagecreatefrompng('watermark.png');   

    // getting dimensions of watermark image
    $watermark_width = imagesx($watermark);  
    $watermark_height = imagesy($watermark);  

//image path
     $image_path = 'path/to/image'; 

    // creating jpg from original image
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_path);
    //something went wrong 
    if ($image === false) {
        return false;
    } 
    // getting the dimensions of original image
    $size = getimagesize($image_path); 

    // placing the watermark 5px from bottom and right
    $dest_x = $size[0] - $watermark_width - 5;  
    $dest_y = $size[1] - $watermark_height - 5;

    // blending the images together
    imagealphablending($image, true);
    imagealphablending($watermark, true); 

    // creating the new image
    imagecopy($image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height); 
    imagejpeg($image);  
    // destroying and freeing memory
    imagedestroy($image);  
    imagedestroy($watermark);
```